# Backgroundworker is very slow, how to optimize?

Tags: vb.net, linq, delegates, backgroundworker, invoke

I have the following structure:
**OLD:**
frmMain (WinForm)
uscStat (UserControl with Grid)

In frmMain I'm able to make some settings and load the result of the settings via LinQ into the Grid of the uscStat.
f.e.:
*frmMain*

```
Private Sub rdbValue2_ValueChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles rdbValue2.ValueChanged  
  uscStat.Load(Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4, ...)  
End Sub
```

*uscStat*

```
Public Sub Load(ByVal Value1, ByVal Value2, ByVal Value3, ...)

  ...
  Dim dt As New Datatable
  dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Value1", GetType(Double)
  ...
  Dim res As IEnumerable = ReturnDatable(Value2, Value3, ...)
  Dim rowObj(6) As Object
  ...    
  For each item in res
    rowObj(1) = FuncXY(item.Value1)
    rowObj(2) = item.Value2
    ...
    dt.Rows.Add(rowObj)
  Next

  dg.Datasource = dt
End Sub
```

Takes round about 30 sec, depending on the User-Settings.

**NEW**
Added: modCommon (Module)
To pass all the variables I added the following Class in the module:

```
Public Class clsStatValues
  Public Property Value1() As Boolean
  Get
    Return m_Value1
  End Get
  Set(value As Boolean)
    m_Value1 = value
  End Set
  End Property
  Private m_Value1 As Boolean
  Public Property Value2() As Integer
  Get
    Return m_Value2
  End Get
  Set(value As Integer)
    m_Value2 = value
  End Set
  End Property
  Private m_Value2 As Integer
  ...
End Class
```

And I add the following BackgroundWorker in *modCommon*:

```
Public thStat As Backgroundworker
```

I initialize in *frmMain* thStat:

```
thStat = New BackgroundWorker
AddHandler thStat.DoWork, AddressOf thStat_DoWork
AddHandler thStat.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf thStat_Completed
AddHandler thStat.ProgressChanged, AddressOf thStat_ProgressChanged
thStat.WorkerReportsProgress = True
thStat.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
```

And created the following subs:

```
Private Sub thStat_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)
    Dim varStat As clsStatValues = e.Argument
    uscStat.Load(varStat.Value1, varStat.Value2, ...)
End Sub
```

And changed the settings-subs like:

```
Private Sub rdbValue2_ValueChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles rdbValue2.ValueChanged  
  Dim varStat As New clsStatValues
  varStat.Value1 = True
  varStat.Value2 ...
  ...
  thStat.RunWorkerAsync(varStat) 
End Sub
```

In *uscStat* I changed/added the following:

```
Public Sub Load(ByVal Value1, ...)
  ...
  Me.Invoke(New AddDataSourceToGrid(AddressOf AddDataSourceToGridFunction), GetDatatable(Value1, Value2, ...))
  ...
End Sub

Delegate Sub AddDataSourceToGrid(ByRef tmpDt As DataTable)

Private Sub AddDataSourceToGridFunction(ByRef tmpDt As DataTable)
    dg.DataSource = tmpDt
End Sub

Public Function GetDatatable(ByVal Value1, ByVal Value2, ByVal Value3, ...) As Datatable

  ...
  Dim dt As New Datatable
  dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Value1", GetType(Double)
  ...
  Dim res As IEnumerable = ReturnDatable(Value2, Value3, ...)
  Dim resultCount = res.AsQueryable.Count
  Dim ReportEvery As Double = resultCount/100
  Dim staticReportEvery As Double = ReportEvery
  Dim count As Integer = 0
  Dim Percent As Integer = 0

  Dim rowObj(6) As Object
  ...    
  For each item in res
    count += 1
    If count > ReportEvery then
      Percent += 1
      thStat.ReportProgress(Percent, count & " of " & resultCount)
      ReportEvery += staticReportEvery
    End If
    rowObj(1) = FuncXY(item.Value1)
    rowObj(2) = item.Value2
    ...
    dt.Rows.Add(rowObj)
  Next

  Return dt
End Sub
```

This takes round about 5 mins with the same user-settings, too slow.
How can I improve it?

Comment: ReportProgress is expensive, don't call it for each individual row.  Use a profiler if that doesn't help.

Comment: Hmmm ReportProgress is called a 100 times (1 percent, 2 percent, ...) and not for every row. Is this still too much?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you copy one DataTable into another DataTable and apply FuncXY to a column. I do not know what FuncXY does. Would it be possible to do that with an SQL query? It would be much faster than looping through individual records.

Comment: I don't think that I copy the Datatable, because I pass the variable as reference. Correct me I'm wrong. Put FuncXY directly in SQL? I would first say: no. But I'll think about it. But actually it ran without the Backgroundworker relatively quickly.